# Simple CSS dropdown menu does not work in IE6 or 7

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I'm using a very simple CSS dropdown menu which works well in most modern browsers.  Unfortunately it must also work in IE6 and 7, which it currently does not.  Can anyone please check it out very quickly and tell me if it can be easily fixed?

I'm not adverse to using JavaScript if required.

The markup and CSS: http://paste2.org/p/826583

Comment: Hint: `:hover` doesn't work on other elements than `a` in IE6. The only solution is Javascript. It by the way just works in IE7 here (tested with real IE7 as well as [IETester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)).

Comment: Thanks for testing - I know it barely works in IE7 but the sub-level items seem to "disappear" as you mouseover what would be the 1px border of each top-level menu item.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The :hover pseudo selector doesn't work in IE6 or IE7 (quirks mode) for non-links (your li's for instance).  That's why the [original popular CSS dropdown](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns) included a bit of JavaScript.

If you're still having issues with spacing and such, I would check out the [Son of Suckerfish Dropdowns](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/).  IMO the gold standard of CSS dropdowns.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to debug your CSS, I think you should just start with a menu that is confirmed to work in IE6 and 7. There are many, and if you start with that criteria, you'll save a lot of time.

I use jQuery and droppy. Extremely simple and works on everything.  Once you find one that works, keep using it so you avoid all this waste on any future projects.

Comment: Thanks but I'm genuinely interested to know why my current solution, which is very simple, doesn't work in at least IE7.

Comment: Gotcha. That's fair.  I think developer time is more important than understanding poorly conceived browser design. The time spent debugging arbitrary nuance in old browsers could be better used learning something that you can use moving forward. Maybe. I'm one of these people that never got into memorizing every shortcoming of IE. I prefer to get product out the door. Hence, using techniques confirmed to work all the time and sticking to them.